# java while loop with periodic break receives out of memory exception

Tags: java, loops, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, infinite-loop

I have the following loop that listens for UDP messages coming in

```
 public void run(){

 int count = 0;
        boolean loopRecv = true;
        while (loopRecv) {
                count++;
                if (count == 500) {
                    loopRecv = false;
                    System.out.println("break from loop");

                    count = 0;


                }
            }
 }
```

The problem is that within a few hours, I receive an out of memory exception.  Also I am monitoring the memory in Top and it is growing slowly.

I thought that  breaking from this loop would remove that allocated stack frames, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

How can i run this loop without receiving the out of memory error?

Comment: Technically, I don't think you're getting an OutOfMemoryError.  You mean a StackOverflow, right?

Comment: @AmirAfghani is right, you call yourself recursively!

Comment: Why are you doing this?  There's probably a better way to write this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was opening a database connection before the run and not closing it.

Answer (score 5):

Every 500 iterations of your while loop, you call back into `run`.

```
run()
.
. 500 iterations
.
   run()
   .
   .
   . 500 iterations
   .
      run()
```

Your `loopRecv` boolean is not doing anything.  Though you set `loopRecv` to false, you immediately make the recursive call, rendering the boolean assignment useless!  Hence, the `StackOverflowError`.  Instead, why don't you just find a way to implement your method iteratively instead?  Consider breaking to a [label](http://www.java-examples.com/java-break-statement-label-example).  It's not very clear what your function accomplishes.

Answer (score 0):

You're recursively calling the method every time count == 500. This slows down the StackOverflowError, but it will still happen.

Remove the call to run() from the inside of the while loop and it shouldn't error anymore.

Comment: You mean `StackOverflowError`, since is not an exception.

Answer (score 0):

The common StackOverFolow error comes with an infinity recursive loop that has no terminal and calls itself continuously, in your case, your calling `run ()` even after the condition is true , so if you declare a break point to the while loop you won't get the error.

I am interested of asking why you are calling `run ()` after a condition is true? Is it the matter of interesting or you have some purpose?